# Executing OpenCL code on AMD e8860 GPU

Tags: drivers, centos-7, amd-graphics-card, opencl

I have a relatively simple OpenCL program that I know works on an Nvidia GPU and now I am trying it on an AMD e8860 MxM GPU, but I cannot get it to run using the GPU.  I have tried both the dedicated 8860 AMD drivers and the generic AMD GPU pro drivers for both Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. I can compile the program, but executing makes it run on the CPU, as I see the process in `top` take up 100% of a CPU core. When executing on the Nvidia, `nvidia-smi` shows it is running on the GPU and `top` shows the process as taking up less than 10% of a core.

The 8860 apparently does not support ROCm, so that is not an option.  I am very frustrated with this because I know it works, its just I am not getting the AMD drivers right.

Running clinfo with the pro drivers gives an error and does not say the name of my GPU, so they may not even be compatible with my card.

It should be noted that neither GPU is used as the video source, that is handled by an embedded VGA chip(SM750) and not an integrated GPU.

Also any tools that are similar to `nvidia-smi` for AMD? I just need to see usage and temperature.

System specs are Xeon D1559, running on preferably Centos 7, but Ubuntu will work if it is easier.

Comment: The latest driver seems to be [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-10).

Comment: I can try the latest but I do not see the e8860 as a compatible GPU. Thank you

Comment: You are right - the latest driver for your gpu is [from 2017](https://www.amd.com/en/support/embedded/amd-embedded-radeon/amd-embedded-e-series/e8860).

Comment: I have tried that driver but it won't install on Centos (not surprising, not supported) but on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the driver will install but the program refuses to run on the GPU.  Are you aware of any additional packages/instructions to compile the program to run on the GPU. I know for Nvidia I have to link an OpenCL.so file on Centos, but I am unfamiliar on how to do that on Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, can't help. The newer drivers don't support this gpu.

Comment: Hmmm, so no way to do this using the older 8860 drivers? The GPU says it supports OpenCL. What would be your method if the newer drivers did support this.  I am at my wits end and am willing to try anything